# I'm trying to use int in a for loop but the error message expected type 'collections.iterable' got 'int' instead appears

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to do is use a `for` loop to move a turtle but the error message expected type collections.iterable got int instead I have no idea why this is happening

```
fred = turtle
fred.shape("turtle")
for x in 20:
    fred.width(5)
    fred.forward(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

the error refers to the line

```
for x in 20:
```

`20` is of type `int` and cannot be iterated over you should use `range()`

```
for x in range(20):
```